Trouble with Discord.py "purge" slash command. Unknown message error? (Follow-up response fails to send, causes error.)
I'm using discord.py, and one of my commands is "purge". The problem being is that everytime I use the purge command, it deletes the amount of messages, but the "follow-up" response it is supposed to send causes an error. BE AWARE: This is a SLASH COMMAND.
(Edit: The problem is that when the command is executed by the person, the command runs and deletes the specified amount, but the command pops up with "Application took too long to respond," or nothing at all, followed by an error on my Console. Please bear with me, I'm not entirely scripting this myself. I am still learning Python, so I use AI to help me script without sharing my token to it.)
Tried changing the code more than once, expected it to work normally and send "Purged {amount} messages", but it shows up with "Unknown message" in the error.
Purge command:
    @tree.command(
    name="purge",
    description="Deletes a specified number of messages from the channel."
)
async def purge(interaction: Interaction, amount: int):
    await interaction.response.defer()  # Defers the interaction, giving you more time
    try:
        deleted = await interaction.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)  # +1 to account for the command message itself
        await interaction.followup.send(f"Purged {len(deleted) - 1} messages.")  # Use followup to send the final response
    except Exception as e:
        await interaction.followup.send(f"An error occurred: {e}")

@purge.error
async def purge_error(interaction: Interaction, error):
    try:
        if interaction.response.is_done():
            await interaction.followup.send("An error occurred while executing this command.")
        else:
            if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
                await interaction.response.send_message("You don't have permission to use this command.")
            elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
                await interaction.response.send_message("Please specify the number of messages to purge.")
            elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
                await interaction.response.send_message("Please provide a valid number.")
            else:
                await interaction.response.send_message("An error occurred while executing this command.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to send error message: {e}")

Error Traceback:
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='CommandTree-invoker' coro=<CommandTree._from_interaction.<locals>.wrapper() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/discord.py-2.4.0a5033+gf77ba711-py3.12.egg/discord/app_commands/tree.py:1107> exception=NotFound('404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/discord.py-2.4.0a5033+gf77ba711-py3.12.egg/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 858, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/psylar/Documents/PsylarBot/bot_commands.py", line 26, in purge
    await interaction.followup.send(f"Purged {len(deleted) - 1} messages.")  # Use followup to send the final response
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/discord.py-2.4.0a5033+gf77ba711-py3.12.egg/discord/webhook/async_.py", line 1843, in send
    data = await adapter.execute_webhook(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/discord.py-2.4.0a5033+gf77ba711-py3.12.egg/discord/webhook/async_.py", line 221, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/discord.py-2.4.0a5033+gf77ba711-py3.12.egg/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1268, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/discord.py-2.4.0a5033+gf77ba711-py3.12.egg/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 883, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/discord.py-2.4.0a5033+gf77ba711-py3.12.egg/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 876, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'purge' raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/discord.py-2.4.0a5033+gf77ba711-py3.12.egg/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1109, in wrapper
    await self._call(interaction)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/discord.py-2.4.0a5033+gf77ba711-py3.12.egg/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1271, in _call
    await command._invoke_error_handlers(interaction, e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/discord.py-2.4.0a5033+gf77ba711-py3.12.egg/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 802, in _invoke_error_handlers
    await self.on_error(interaction, error)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/psylar/Documents/PsylarBot/bot_commands.py", line 31, in purge_error
    await interaction.followup.send("An error occurred while executing this command.")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/discord.py-2.4.0a5033+gf77ba711-py3.12.egg/discord/webhook/async_.py", line 1843, in send
    data = await adapter.execute_webhook(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/discord.py-2.4.0a5033+gf77ba711-py3.12.egg/discord/webhook/async_.py", line 221, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The problem seems to be that the interaction you're trying to respond with wasn't found:
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message
then you're trying to respond again with the same interaction.
So you get the same error twice.
The solultion is to handle the case like this:
async def purge(interaction: Interaction, amount: int):

    await interaction.response.defer()  # Defers the interaction, giving you more time

    channel = interaction.channel
    try:
        deleted = await interaction.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)  # +1 to account for the command message itself
        await interaction.followup.send(f"Purged {len(deleted) - 1} messages.")  # Use followup to send the final response
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            await interaction.followup.send(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        except discord.errors.NotFound: 
            await channel.send(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    


Should I show you the full of my bot_commands code?

Got it fixed! Just switched "interaction.followup.send" to "channel.send," considering the "channel" variable is "interaction.channel".

That's great news! Could you upvote or accept the answer? I'm tryng to get 50 rep.(that's the only reason I answered your question xD)

Can't cast a vote unless I have 15 rep apparently
